# How to get Acer AspireOne netbook to re-recognize its webcam?

Tags: netbook, camera, acer-aspire-one

I have an Acer Aspireone netbook that refuses to recognize its camera.  The model of the netbook is an A0A150, and it is running windows XP SP3.  In the device manager, under the usb devices section there is an "unknown device".  I tried uninstalling this, and scanning for hardware, but no luck.  I also tried updating the driver directly with drivers I downloaded, but with no success so far.  Attempting to run the setup insists that I connect the camera, but as it is integratd, I cannot.  I am fairly sure this is a software, not a hardware, issue.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

has the webcam been working before or is this a fresh installation, possible nLited, as it is very popular with netbooks?

Windows XP automatically detects this webcam and will install a generic driver for the webcam, it will then show in My Computer as USB Video Device, unless necessary components have been removed from the installation disk.

Answer (score 0):

I had my call elevated to the Level II technician.  It turns out the problem is not with the camera, but with the motherboard.  The internal connection between the motherboard and the camera is defective.  Acer is picking up my computer (because they misdiagnosed the problem the first time in May) to repair it.  I suggest you call Acer Tech Service and ask to speak to a Level II Tech Support person.

Good Luck